# Filter Error Messages from log real time

Tags: java, logging, jboss, logback, appender

I have `ear` of my project and it is successfully working. In the `Jboss` log all the messages are printed.(`INFO`, `DEBUG`, `WARN`, `ERROR`. etc...)

Now I am trying to build a web app to show all `ERROR` messages real time.(the moment `ERROR` occurred). Currently I am planning to call a web service. Then I can show the messages in real time through the web app.

I have tried with logback(http://logback.qos.ch/) following and it is working for standalone only.

`logback.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="com.test.MyAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level  %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

`MyAppender` class.

```
public class MyAppender extends ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAppender.class);
    public static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private String endpointUrl;

    @Override
    public void append(Object eventObject) {
        list.add(eventObject);           
        sendRequestToRESTAPI(eventObject);// calling the web service
    }    

}
```

This standalone application works fine. when ever the `error` occurred `append()` method will call.

But this approach is not working with `Jboss` since `append()` is not triggered. I am not sure the reason since I am new to `Jboss`. But I think that will be issue with `Jboss` log Adapter. How can i change this to work with `Jboss`.?

Comment: *"But this approach is not working with Jboss"* - Why?  What is it saying?

Comment: @StephenC If I know the exact reason i will not be here to ask this question. I have edited my question to clarify more.